# Conservation of momentum/energy and Casimir effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, casimir-effect

I am looking for an understanding which shows that conservation of momentum is not violated while observing Casimir effect? The link for Casimir effect is

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect

It appears we are tapping energy from the vacuum so how momentum/energy is conserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Momentum is easily conserved by the [two plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Casimir_plates.svg) , for example. They will acquire an equal and opposite momentum.

Did you mean to ask if energy is conserved?

Energy is conserved in the same way it is conserved when an apple starts falling. It took energy to put the apple at a point where it could fall, it got a potential energy, and turned it to kinetic again by falling. The two plates do not magically appear at that distance. It took energy to be positioned there which became potential energy to be measured in the experiment.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I understood energy conserved part.  Is there a hidden assumption that there is energy in vacuum? Your comment "  It took energy to be positioned there .." may be I am asking why and where it came from?

Comment: @Creator the energy is supplied by the experimenter who sets up the system at a distance that the experiment can measure the effect. Suppose one wants to measure the attraction of two macroscopic charges. If already charged the experimenter who places them close enough for the forces to appear has to supply energy to put them at that distance, if repulsive, or work against the attraction if attractive.

Comment: This is totally unrelated. May I ask your opinion on a mathematical formulation where time is not an orthogonal dimension to space like in Minkowski space. This formulation would lead to another parameter to our model. Is this model be helpful in any aspect?  Would you please comment?

Comment: Orthogonal systems offer a simple mathematical formulation for physics models. Anything non orthogonal has to be broken up to two orthogonal components  so as to simplify the formulae used. So no it would not help introducing non orthogonal directions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But if orthogonal, it has no component on it's orthogonal components.  In sense, in the present formulation the time dimension cannot have a projection into space dimension. I am questioning this limitation.  In extreme microscopic limit, ca we postulate time is non-orthogonal, so space does not have it's own independent entity. More specifically, the time component may not be same in all three space dimensions.

Comment: Orthonormality is just mathematics simplifying a model. Sure the time component is different in different inertial spaces . look up  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation Maybe you should read and understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis

Comment: Sorry, for my repeated question, time dilation related to object moving at different speed, I was thinking of  defining stationary object.  Orthogonality is mathematically easy but mat not be reality. So with different time axis for x.y.z, space w may get a different formulation.

Comment: reality can always be modeed as expanded into an orthogonal set. this is mathematics. Any function can be approximated with a fourier expansion, for example (much more complicated then four or ten spacetime dimensions). If you are thinking of non orthogonal you need two time dimensitons orthogonal to each other. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_time_dimensions

Comment: Thank you so much for bearing with me, The Wikipedia link seems  just an extension of special relativity (speed of light constant) assuming multiple time dimension. The non-orthogonal time can lead to the possibility that here is one space dimension but we are observing 3 (at an instant of time ) as the projection is different due to oblique time axis.

Comment: Imo this will not work mathematically.